# Django formset view in template in reverse order

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms, formset

I am using modelformset_factory and view formset data in template. If you look at below image the template is showing data in 1st image. But i want to view the formset in reverse order like in 2nd image. First i will have new data enter textbox. Then the old data will be listed in reverse order like it is done in 2nd image.

[image]

My model is :

```
class AssistantNotes(BaseModel):
    categories = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES, max_length=100, verbose_name=_("Kategori"))
    dailynote = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Not Ekle"))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s / %s" % (self.dailynote, self.categories)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['dailynote']
```

Then i created below view.

```
def create_assistant_notes(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if AssistantNotes.objects.count() == 0:
            file_write("get000")
            AssistantNotesFormsetFactory = modelformset_factory(AssistantNotes, fields=('categories', 'dailynote',))
        else:
            file_write("get111")
            AssistantNotesFormsetFactory = modelformset_factory(AssistantNotes, fields=('categories', 'dailynote',), can_delete=True)
        formset = AssistantNotesFormsetFactory(queryset=AssistantNotes.objects.all())
        helper = TableInlineHelper()
        return render(request, 'create-assistant-notes.html', {'formset': formset, 'helper': helper})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if AssistantNotes.objects.count() == 0:
            AssistantNotesFormsetFactory = modelformset_factory(AssistantNotes, fields=('categories', 'dailynote',))
        else:
            AssistantNotesFormsetFactory = modelformset_factory(AssistantNotes, fields=('categories', 'dailynote',), can_delete=True)
        formset = AssistantNotesFormsetFactory(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        else:
            helper = TableInlineHelper()
            return render(request, 'create-assistant-notes.html', {'formset': formset, 'helper': helper})
        return redirect(reverse('create-assistant-notes'))
```

My template html file is;

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}    
{% block title %}{% trans "Notes" %}{% endblock title %}    
{% block content %}
<div class="block-area" id="basic">
    <form role="form" method="post">
        {% crispy formset helper %}
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-alt">{% trans "Save" %}</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-alt" data-dismiss="modal">{% trans "Cancel" %}</button> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: It's not documented, but you can use [`formset.initial_forms`](https://github.com/django/django/blame/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/forms/formsets.py#L176) and [`formset.extra_forms`](https://github.com/django/django/blame/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/forms/formsets.py#L181) to get the initial and extra forms respectively. Your question is slightly trickier because you're using crispy forms - I'm not sure how you would get crispy forms to render those two lists of forms.

Comment: I think i should put a request to Django framework developers :)